# gCloud Container (GKE) Kubernetes Service Port 8000 unreachable

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am getting this error, when I am trying to access the Public IP's http exposure.

```
RajRajen:lb4btest rajrajen$ curl http://104.154.84.143:8000
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

RajRajen:lb4btest rajrajen$ telnet 104.154.84.143 8000
Trying 104.154.84.143...
Connected to 143.84.154.104.bc.googleusercontent.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
RajRajen:lb4btest rajrajen$
```

< Pls note the above IP is just representation , Once I redeploy, the IP may change. But the problem is not >

Controller URL as it in in my json file .

```
RajRajen:lb4btest rajrajen$ kubectl create -f middleware-service.json 
services/lb4b-api-v9
```

And the rc - replication controller json file.

```
{
"kind": "ReplicationController",
"apiVersion": "v1",
"metadata": {
  "name": "lb4b-api-v9",
  "labels": {
    "app": "lb4bapi",
    "tier": "middleware"
}
},
"spec": {
"replicas": 1,
"selector": {
  "app": "lb4bapi",
  "tier": "middleware"
},
"template": {
  "metadata": {
    "labels": {
      "app": "lb4bapi",
      "tier": "middleware"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "containers": [
      {
        "name": "lb4bapicontainer",
        "image": "gcr.io/helloworldnodejs-1119/myproject",
        "resources": {
          "requests": {
            "cpu": "500m",
            "memory": "128Mi"
          }
        },
        "env": [
          {
            "name": "GET_HOSTS_FROM",
            "value": "dns"
          },
          {
            "name": "PORT",
            "value": "8000"
          }
        ],
        "ports": [
          {
            "name": "middleware",
            "containerPort": 8000,
            "hostPort": 8000
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
}
}
```

And here is the service json file

```
{
"kind": "Service",
"apiVersion": "v1",
"metadata": {
  "name": "lb4b-api-v9",
  "labels": {
      "name": "lb4b-api-v9",
      "app": "lb4bmiddleware",
      "tier": "middleware"
  }    
},    
"spec": {
    "type": "LoadBalancer",
    "selector": {
        "name": "lb4b-api-v9",            
        "app": "lb4bmiddleware",
        "tier": "middleware"
    },
    "ports": [
        {
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "port": 8000
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Docker container is running a node application as **non-root** user as per the pm2 requirement .

```
 ENTRYPOINT ["pm2"]
 CMD ["start", "app.js", "--no-daemon"]
```

I am perfectly able to do curl on this POD Local IP  curl http://podIP:podPort inside the POD docker as well as inside the NODE.
   But unable to do curl on http://serviceLocalIP:8000 inside the NODE.

Can you please give some suggestions to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved.. After following the troubleshooting comment about the Service Endpoint, especially keeping the SERVICE selector value same as in POD selector value.

https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/debugging/

Search for **My service is missing endpoints**

Solution in Controller.json

```
     {
 "kind": "ReplicationController",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
   "name": "lb4b-api-v9",
   "labels": {
         "name": "lb4b-api-v9",            
        "app": "lb4bmiddleware",
        "tier": "middleware"
  }
},
"spec": {
"replicas": 1,
"selector": {
        **"name": "lb4b-api-v9",            
        "app": "lb4bmiddleware",
        "tier": "middleware"**
},
"template": {
  "metadata": {
    "labels": {
        "name": "lb4b-api-v9",            
        "app": "lb4bmiddleware",
        "tier": "middleware"
     }
        },
        "spec": {
      "containers": [
      {
        "name": "lb4b-api-v9",
        "image": "gcr.io/myprojectid/myproect",
        "resources": {
          "requests": {
            "cpu": "500m",
            "memory": "128Mi"
          }
        },
        "env": [
          {
            "name": "GET_HOSTS_FROM",
            "value": "dns"
          },
          {
            "name": "PORT",
            "value": "8000"
          }
        ],
        "ports": [
          {
            "name": "middleware",
            "containerPort": 8000,
            "hostPort": 8000
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
}
}
```

And in Service.json

```
 {
"kind": "Service",
"apiVersion": "v1",
"metadata": {
  "name": "lb4b-api-v9",
  "labels": {
      "name": "lb4b-api-v9",
      "app": "lb4bmiddleware",
      "tier": "middleware"
  }    
},    
"spec": {
    "type": "LoadBalancer",
    "selector": {
        **"name": "lb4b-api-v9",            
        "app": "lb4bmiddleware",
        "tier": "middleware"**
    },
    "ports": [
        {
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "port": 8000
        }
    ]
}
 }
```

Thats all..